# How to set arrays as parameters of the SQL query

Tags: sql, go, clickhouse

Let's say some front end application send `POST` request with such body to the back end (Go) application:

```
{
    "city": "London",
    "gender": ["Female", "Male"],
    "has_family": [0, 1]
}
```

As you can see request body has two arrays. I am trying to set these arrays into the SQL query. In my case I make SQL query to the `ClickHouse` database. I use [go-clickhouse](http://github.com/mailru/go-clickhouse) package for this task.

I tried such code but it raises an error:

> sql: converting argument $2 type: unsupported type []string, a slice
>   of string

Also, I tried to change the data type from `[]string` to `[]interface{}`. Unfortunately, in that case, it raises an error like:

> sql: converting argument $2 type: unsupported type []interface {}, a
>   slice of interface

**Code**:

```
var Controller = func(responseWriter http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    type RequestBody struct {
        City string `json:"city"`
        Gender []string `json:"gender"`
        HasFamily []int `json:"has_family"`
    }

    requestBody := RequestBody{}

    decoder := json.NewDecoder(request.Body)

    if err := decoder.Decode(&requestBody); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    rows, err := database.ClickHouse.Query("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE lower(CITY) = lower($1) AND GENDER IN ($2) AND HAS_FAMILY IN ($3);", requestBody.City, requestBody.Gender, requestBody.HasFamily)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    // other code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to wrap `requestBody.Gender` and `requestBody.HasFamily` with `clickhouse.Array()`. And also try to change the `$n` to `?`.

Code:

```golang
rows, err := database.ClickHouse.Query(
    "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE lower(CITY) = lower(?) AND GENDER IN (?) AND HAS_FAMILY IN (?);",
    requestBody.City,
    clickhouse.Array(requestBody.Gender),
    clickhouse.Array(requestBody.HasFamily),
)
```

More info: https://godoc.org/github.com/mailru/go-clickhouse#Array

Comment: Thank you for your replay! I tried to test your code but it raises an error: `clickhouse: Code: 53, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Type mismatch in IN or VALUES section. Expected: String. Got: Array (version 19.14.6.12 (official build))`. Also I notice that `$1`, `$2` and `$3` raise such error: `clickhouse: wrong placeholder count`. For thats why I change them to `?`. Do you have any ideas about that?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek just updated my answer. btw can you please share the table scheme as well? wanted to ensure the columns' data type are valid

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek regarding the `$n`, I checked on the source code, it is not valid placeholder syntax. the `?` is the one that used on the library

Comment: The data type of the `CITY` column is `String`. The data type of the `Gender` column is also `String`. The data type of the `HAS_FAMILY` column is `UInt8`.

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek I though `Gender` and `HAS_FAMILY` was `Array`. if it is not an array then you need to join the values with separator `,`

Comment: You are right. In other words, I'm trying to create such SQL query: `SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE lower(CITY) = lower("London") AND GENDER IN ("Female", "Male") AND HAS_FAMILY IN (0, 1);`. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek instead of `IN ($2)` which takes a list of values, not an array, use `= ANY($2::text[])`. Or `IN` can be executed with a subquery, so `IN (SELECT unnest($2::text[]))`.

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek also it is "reply", the word "replay" means something entirely different.

Comment: @mkopriva sorry for the typo in the word. It was an accident. It seems like `ClickHouse` doesn't have `ANY` statement. Also `$n` is not valid placeholder syntax. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek then use `?`, I've used `$2` only because that's what's in your question. If ClickHouse doesn't support `ANY/SOME`, and it doesn't have an equivalent to `unnest` then you can simply build out the `(?, ?, ? ...)` string yourself, append it to the query, aggregate the individual slice elements and other parameters into a single `[]interface{}` and then pass that to the `Query` func with the three-dots suffix (e.g. `paramslice...`).